# Curved text is not perpendicular to the curve

Tags: text-object, curve-modifier

I made text that is curved according to a curve using Curve modifier placed on the text. For some reason, individual letters of the text are not perpendicular to the curve (as I would expect) but are skewed to side the more from center they are placed. See this example:
[image]

Although I know I can use Shear parameter to correct it somewhat, the letters are still deformed as you can see here:
[image]

Can anyone explain to me what is wrong and how to correct the letters so they'd be perpendicular to the curve + not being deformed (squeezed), please?

Here is my test blend file:

[image]

Comment: Hello, the font are part of your computer so we can't see it as it should be, with the default font it works fine, maybe you should convert your text to mesh, see if it works, and share again if it doesn't?

Comment: aha, so you are suggesting the possibility it is actually a font thing? Hmm, gonna check with some Arial font...

Comment: I'm not sure but anyway we can't see what's happening with the font you're using

Comment: OK, tested with Arial Regular and blender's Bfont - deformation is still there, exactly the same: it looks to me like a "balooning effect"/"expanding universe": anything on the surface of baloon gets more and more deformed the more the baloon is filled with air (hope it makes sense). With that being said: problem is elsewhere, not in the font used. (or at least it looks that way to me).

Comment: ...I mean the penpendicularity problem improves/is gone as IT WAS THE FONT I USED BEING ITALIZED TO AN EXTEND, BUT THE SQUEEZING DEFORMATION of the letters still remain.

Comment: You need to put the Shear value at 0: https://zupimages.net/up/23/39/efx1.jpg Also you need to apply the scale in Object mode

Comment: I know that, I already have Shear at 0, yet the squeezing deformatrion is still there. - it'd be great if I could make animated short gif showing how it is deformed more and more the more I move the font up or downward.

Comment: the more you'll move away from the curve the more it will deform, this is normal, the shear is not normal though

Comment: test it yourself: replace the font for, let's say, Arial Regular, and move the font upward and downward - the more extreme you go the more the squeezing deformation will occur. Oh, you posted before I post my...so the "effect" is expected? Gee, what now?

Comment: If you're talking about that, this is expected: https://zupimages.net/up/23/39/ymbc.gif

Comment: It looks like I just find out the reason for the squeezing deformation: to have the font not deformed IT HAS TO SIT DIRECTLY ON THE CURVE - if it is anywhere above it or below it the more distant it is the more deformed it becomes. So now as I adjusted POSITION OF THE CURVE ITSELF to the place I want my font would actually sit and also adjusted the font position so it sits directly on the curve it seems to be OK. Am I right with this?

Comment: sure but it doesn't explain the shear you were talking about, did you fix it?

Comment: Yes, I did and I already explained it in one of the answers, maybe you just did not noticed: it was the special font that was like being already italized (skewed to the right) by default, so in that regard you were right it might be the actual font problem which it was. So it looks like I will give a solution with new post explaining the curve-text connection (position of the text to the actual curve used for the curving).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the solution is this, namely:

**skewing:** in fact, as @moonboots suggested, it turns out to be problem of the special font I used as I found out it was kind of already italized font type by default (font being skewed to the right), so changing the font solved the skewing I had (tho I really do need that exact font so in this specific case I solved it by adjusting text tool's Smear parameter).

**squeezing deformation:** I found out that the problem lays in the curve exact position used for the curving of the text. The curve needs to sit exactly at the place where the bottom of the text is expected to be (as I thought it doesn't matter and all I need to care about was the shape of the curve itself, not its position - wrong!) cos else the more you are from that position the more the font is deformed (squeezed) which is normal and expected, as I was told. Thus once I updated the curve position and also re-adjusted the font position accordingly all is OK and there is no deformation anymore (or it is not visible at least to me).